# Вылетает unity при столкновении префаба с префабом

Tags: unity3d

https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aq1DWDtFXmvfgbJwYl8kiZFnOyuTQw

Когда объект касается пола, всё работает как надо. А когда объект касается другого объекта, вылезает ошибка о нехватке памяти. Код сто раз проверил, ошибок не нашёл, поэтому залил весь проект на onedrive. Будьте добры. Версия 2019.2.1f1

Код отвечающий за столкновение:

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Floor" || other.gameObject.tag == "Block")
    {
        transform_obj = false;
        GameObject.Find("Game Controller").GetComponent<GameController>().SpawnNewBlocks();
    }
```

В этом коде функция SpawnNewBlocks

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject[] blocks;
private int random_index;
int size_blocks;

void Start()
{
    size_blocks = blocks.Length;
    SpawnNewBlocks();
}

public void SpawnNewBlocks()
{
    random_index = Random.Range(0, size_blocks);
    Instantiate(blocks[random_index]);
}
```

Comment: нет возможности скачать проект, поэтому прошу вас показать хотя бы код обработки коллизии объектов

Comment: При столкновении объекта с полом и объекта с объектом вызывается по факту один и тот же код.

Comment: Очевидно, метод `SpawnNewBlocks()` и вызывает проблему. Приведите **весь** код в вопрос.

Comment: конечно, информации мало, но я думаю, что `SpawnNewBlocks()` спавнит кучу новых объектов которые сразу сталкиваются с игроком или друг с другом и метод обработки столкновения вызывается лавинообразно

Comment: При столкновении с floor всё работает как надо. Это тетрис если что.

Comment: Ну вот, блоки создаются в непонятном месте, что и может привести, как сказали выше, к лавинообразному срабатыванию OnTriggerEnter

Comment: может я и не в свои сани лезу, но использование физики юнити для тетриса не кажется мне оптимальным решением, я бы сделал 2д массив блоков и столкновения блоков проверял бы там

Comment: Если я вас правильно понял, если приписать debug.log в функцию OnTriggerEnter, в консоли должна быть куча сообщения при спавне. Этого нет.

Comment: Уберите строку со спавном нового блока и увидите результат

Comment: из своего опыта могу вам точно сказать, что использовать физику в тетрисе это действительно плохая идея. Всё, что вам нужно - двумерный массив и проверка соседних элементов массива.

Comment: Это не совсем обычный тетрис. Вариант с массивом не пойдет. Поэтому так. Хочется чтобы всё работало в том виде, в котором оно есть.

Comment: Приведите скриншоты до/после инстанциирования методом SpawnNewBlocks, в таком виде ответить сложно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проект не смотрел, не скажу, что по памяти, но выглядит так, как будто вместо

```
random_index = Random.Range(0, size_blocks);
```

Должно быть

```
random_index = Random.Range(0, size_blocks-1);
```

**Дополнено.**
Как заметил trollingchar, проблема не в этом.

Открыл Ваш проект.

1) Поменяйте Ваш if следующим образом:

```
 if (other.gameObject.tag == "Floor" || other.gameObject.tag == "Block")
 {
    transform_obj = false;
    GameObject.Find("Game Controller").GetComponent<GameController>().SpawnNewBlocks();
    Destroy(this);
 }
```

2) Ваш префаб G состоит из объектов Cube. Уберите с них коллайдеры, оставьте только на самом G.

Надеюсь, поможет. Если будут вопросы, рад буду ответить.

Comment: Правая граница не включается при вызове функции с целочисленными параметрами ([документация](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html)), так что проблема не в этом

Comment: @trollingchar Да, действительно, Вы правы, мне почему-то вспомнился float.